# What are the substitute verbs for the modal auxiliary verb 'may/might' when talking about possibility?

Tags: modal-verbs

He *can* play. = He *is **able** to* play.

He *cannot* play. = He *is **unable** to* play.

He *must not* play. = He *is **forbidden** to* play. He *is **prohibited** from* playing.

He *must* play. = He *is **compelled/forced/obliged** to* play. He ***has** to* play.

He *should* play. = He *is **advised** to* play. or He *is **likely/expected/supposed** to* play. It is probable that he will.

He *may* play. = He *is **allowed** to* play. or He *is **???** to* play. It is possible that he will.

Is there an ordinary verb, an adjective, or a past participle, which can replace 'may/might' in a sentence that has a personal noun or pronoun, and not the preparatory 'it' as subject?

Comment: 'He is uncertain to play' goes beyond 'It is possible that he will play' to 'It is fairly unlikely that he will play'. 'He's a possible' doubtless uses 'possible' nounally.

Comment: Depending on context, you might get away with “he is available to play”, ie there is nothing to prevent him playing.

Comment: poised, allowable/permissed, "within possibility", conceivable, prospective

Comment: readi-able, prepared, readied, ready, preparable, doable

Answer (score 2):

- He is liable to play.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/liable?)) liable to do something — likely to do something

[This dictionary](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/liable) adds the word "probable" to the definition of "liable" (which is not yet "possible" but is nevertheless close in meaning).

> probable, likely, or capable
> It's liable to happen soon

Comment: I gave up because I couldn't think of a decent answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: ... which is why this website exists, right? To try and give answers to questions whose answers are not easily found in reference books...

Comment: @user58319 The comment is under the answer, not the question. 'Liable' talks about _probability_, not _possibility_ (though admittedly the question becomes less clear in the 5th stanza).

Answer (score 0):

> He *may* play. = He is **unsure** about playing / to play
>
> (or *We are unsure about his playing*)

---

> There are always politicians who try to win through violence what they
> **are unsure to win** through civilised politicking. [*West Africa*, Issues 4335-4365](https://www.google.com/books/edition/West_Africa/DBEOAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22they%20are%20unsure%20to%22&dq=%22they%20are%20unsure%20to%22&printsec=frontcover) p.39

> Party leaders want to maximize votes when they **are unsure about
> winning**, but at some British elections in this period the
> Conservatives were certain to win anyway. [Patrick Dunleavy;
> *Democracy, Bureaucracy and Public Choice*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Democracy_Bureaucracy_and_Public_Choice/dGu4AwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22they%20are%20unsure%20about%20winning%22&pg=PA105&printsec=frontcover) p.105